# Getting CORS while using YTDL core in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cors, ytdl

I have this simple component that lists all the available formats along with their mime type. I have used ytdl and ytdl-core in my react app. Here is the what I have tried.

```
import React from 'react';
import ytdl from 'ytdl-core';
const YoutubeDownload=()=> {
    const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Submitted");
        fetchFormats();
    }

     const fetchFormats=()=>{
        let link="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mD6StqjD9c";
        let info=ytdl.getInfo("-mD6StqjD9c");
        console.log(info.formats);
    }
    return (  <>
    <article>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className='form-control'>
                <label>Video Link</label>
           <input type="text" id="videoLink"></input>
           </div>
           <div className='form-control'>
        <button className='btn' >Submit </button>
        </div>
        </form>
        </article>
    </>);
}
```

When I click on the submit button CORS error comes up and it fails to fetch the data. Internet shows that you need to add the access control origin on the server which is not possible in my case. Is there any way I can do it in react as I have seen some ways that suggests making a node.js server and use cors package there

Answer (score 0):

Well, In this case. I suggest you use [CORS Anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)

Open that webpage link above and click on the Request Access button.
Then append the YouTube URL like this.

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://youtube.comyour-video`

This is only for the development environment. You don't need this on production.